# Using .Find (find/replace) with Track Changes Creates Duplicates

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a Word VBA macro to optimize the word of my editorial staff. They receive documents and make common corrections using track changes, and then the original author accepts (or rejects) those edits.

The problem is that the macro's use of Find-Replace is resulting in duplicates or even triplicates of the same word because the macro keeps detecting the original and re-replacing it.

In this example, the company name is "NorthWinds" and we want to find and fix incorrect capitalization and posessives (northwinds, northWinds, etc; plus northwinds' or NorthWinds'; and also northwind's or NorthWind's)

Example text:
This is northwinds’ property
This is northwind’s property
This is NorthWinds’ property
This is NorthWind’s property

Result after running the macro with Track Changes turned on:
This is northwinds’ NorthWinds property
This is northwind’s NorthWinds property
This is NorthWindsNorthWinds’ NorthWinds property
This is NorthWind’s NorthWinds property

The Macro:

```
Sub NWFIX()
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Call StrReplace("northwinds' ", "NorthWinds ")
Call StrReplace("northwind's ", "NorthWinds ")
Call StrReplace("NorthWinds.com", "northwinds.com", , True)
Call StrReplace("NorthWinds", "NorthWinds", , True)
Call StrReplace("north winds", "NorthWinds")
End Sub

Sub StrReplace(OldStr As String, NewStr As String, _
Optional WholeWord = False, _
Optional MatchCase = False, _
Optional WildCard = False)

 Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = OldStr
        .Replacement.Text = NewStr
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = MatchCase
        .MatchWholeWord = WholeWord
        .MatchWildcards = WildCard
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Any hints or pointers in the right direction are appreciated!

- Leon

Comment: Your example works as expected for me in Word2016.  I get the updated text with the replaced text showing a strikethrough (track changes on) and the final version has just the new text.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. I'm running on Word O365 16.0.010730.20280 and can replicate these results on multiple windows and mac systems. So I'm not sure where things are falling down.

Answer (score 0):

Leon,

First, I'd recommend re-writing this so that you don't use `Selection` at all, and instead define a range (`set rng = ActiveDocument.Content`), find across the range, and use a `Do While .Found = True` loop to iterate across the circumstances. This is best practice, as `Selection` is messy. Going forward you will find that ranges are just better, even though they're a little more work to set up.

On to your problem at hand, I believe it will be fixed using by replacing `Wrap = wdFindContinue` with `Wrap = wdFindStop`. This will of course stop the sub when your selection reaches the last occurrence, but because you're using `.HomeKey` that shouldn't be an issue.

My system doesn't have O365, so you'll have to report back with your results.